# Send blob-data along with a string to backend

Tags: node.js, pdf, post, blob, backend

I´ve got a weird problem.
Using Node, React, Express, MongoDB -> MERN Stack.

So my page generates a PDF file which then gets send to the backend (as blob data) and is being stored on there.
The problem I have, now I need to send a payment ID along with that blob data to save the order in the data base. I need both in one post request, to make it as smooth as possible:

```
 await axios
        .post(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_API + '/payment/cash', {
          blobData,
          paymentId
        })
        .then(async (res) => ...
```

like so.

Before, when I just sent the blob data, I could simply access the data in the backend by writing:

```
exports.createCashOrder = async (req, res) => {
  const { filename } = req.file; // THIS RIGHT HERE
  const fileHash = await genFileHash(filename);

  try {
    await saveOrder(filename, fileHash, "cash", paymentId);
    //await sendOrderCreatedEmail(req.body, fileHash);
    //await sendOrderReceivedConfirmEmail(req.body, fileHash);
    res.send({ filename: filename });
  }
```

But that doesn't work anymore. I dont have access to that file object anymore when sending that request object.
Neither by trying

```
req.body.blobData
req.body.blobData.file
req.file
```

Any idea how to achieve that, except from making two seperate post requests?

Glad for any help, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Send the data as a form

```js
 await axios
        .postForm(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_API + '/payment/cash', {
          blobData,
          paymentId
        })
        .then(async (res) => ...
```

And then use [multer middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html) to handle the form in express.

Comment: Awesome thanks! 
Will directly try tomorrow. Looks exactly like what I was looking for.